# Mixxx will not recognize all inputs and outputs on NI Audio 4DJ soundcard

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I can't seem to select the two different inputs (4 channels) and two outputs (4 Channels) on this soundcard. Ubuntu/Mixxx only seems to recognize one input (2 channels) and every time I select the one available Mixxx says it can't connect. Any help would be greatly appreciated I feel this is a problem with either pulse audio or alsa not mapping all the channels

Answer (score 2):

You will need to suspend pulse audio while you use Mixxx.

The Mixxx .desktop (Mixxx shortcut) file should call it but it appears it does not. You might want to file a bug.

To do it manually you can simply execute the following in gnome's terminal:

```
pasuspender mixxx
```

If you still do not see all the inputs please refer to this page: http://www.pogo.org.uk/~mark/linuxdj/