# Audio capture from multiple USB sound cards In Lubuntu

Tags: sound, lubuntu, alsa

How do i capture sound from multiple sound cards simultaneously in lubuntu 14.04? At the moment I have installed Audacity but it can only record sound from a single device at a time. Is there any mixer application or terminal commands that can enable me to capture audio from 4 different sound cards simultaneously? 
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This will blow up if the devices aren't synchronized, and might exceed the USB bandwidth limits, but see [How to get a NI Traktor Audio 2 sound card work with Mixxx](http://askubuntu.com/questions/214749/how-to-get-a-ni-traktor-audio-2-sound-card-work-with-mixxx).